# Ruby devkit installing issue

Tags: ruby, windows, devkit

I've been trying to install ruby dev kit and following the instruction on this page.
 http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-04.html

My problem is that when I run rb.dk in the devkit directory, it quits before i am able to do anything (so i am not able to follow next steps).

I really appreciate all help.

Comment: is that dk.rb, and not rb.dk? and how are you running the file, by double-clicking on it?

Comment: oh, yeah it is dk.rb of course.I double clicked it after i associated the rb extension with the ruby CUI interpreter

Comment: @jtzero 'is that dk.rb, and not rb.dk?' LOL!!!

Answer (score 0):

run it in a `cmd` prompt as `C:\Ruby\devkit>ruby dk.rb`.
Running it by associating the CLI with the file causes the cmd prompt to close as soon as the ruby interpreter stops.